# spray-json Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for Class

Tags: scala, spray-json

I still get the same error, I have defined the marshaller (and imported it); it appears that the case class entry is not in context when the function is polymorphic. and this throws a `Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for Case Class`. Is there a reason why spray-json can not find the implicit marshaller for the case class, (even when defined) is this case class in context? Link to [marshaller](https://gist.github.com/ianjuma/2b5c2bc72a55cae5a1c32b0b130728e9)

```
import spray.json._
import queue.MedusaJsonProtocol._

object MysqlDb {
 ...
}

case class UserDbEntry(
  id: Int,
  username: String,
  countryId: Int,
  created: LocalDateTime
)

trait MysqlDb {
  implicit lazy val pool = MysqlDb.pool
}

trait HydraMapperT extends MysqlDb {
  val FetchAllSql: String
  def fetchAll(currentDate: String): Future[List[HydraDbRow]]

  def getJson[T](row: T): String
}

object UserHydraDbMapper extends HydraMapperT {
  override val FetchAllSql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE created >= ?"

  override def fetchAll(currentDate: String): Future[List[UserDbEntry]] = {
    pool.sendPreparedStatement(FetchAllSql, Array(currentDate)).map { queryResult =>
      queryResult.rows match {
        case Some(rows) =>
          rows.toList map (x => rowToModel(x))
        case None => List()
      }
    }
  }

  override def getJson[UserDbEntry](row: UserDbEntry): String = {
      HydraQueueMessage(
        tableType = HydraTableName.UserTable,
        payload = row.toJson.toString()
      ).toJson.toString()
  }

  private def rowToModel(row: RowData): UserDbEntry = {
    UserDbEntry (
      id        = row("id").asInstanceOf[Int],
      username  = row("username").asInstanceOf[String],
      countryId = row("country_id").asInstanceOf[Int],
      created   = row("created").asInstanceOf[LocalDateTime]
    )
  }
}
```

`payload = row.toJson.toString()` Can't find marshaller for UserDbEntry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `UserDbEntry` locally and there is no JSON marshaller for that type. Add the following:

```
 implicit val userDbEntryFormat = Json.format[UserDbEntry]
```

I'm not sure how you can call `row.toJson` given `UserDbEntry` is a local case class. There must be a macro in there somewhere, but it's fairly clear that it's not in scope for the local `UserDbEntry`.

### Edit

Now that I see [your Gist](https://gist.github.com/ianjuma/2b5c2bc72a55cae5a1c32b0b130728e9#file-marshaller-scala-L34), it looks like you have a package dependency problem. As designed, it'll be circular. You have defined the JSON marshaller in `package com.at.medusa.core.queue`, which imports `UserDbEntry`, which depends on `package com.at.medusa.core.queue` for marshalling.

Comment: No, I have implicit marshallers defined elsewhere; I just don't understand why this is the case. I have edited the section, as you can see I  ```import queue.MedusaJsonProtocol._``` DateTimeFormat can not be marshalled with spray-json, you have to define a custom marshaller.

Comment: Where ever you have them defined, they are not in scope. You'll have to include it. Maybe add a Gist for both files.